# Why does devtools::document() try to document tests?

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I'm working on a package ([this one](https://github.com/mablab/rpostgisLT/tree/dev)) where I set up my tests according to the [testthat workflow](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html). This includes having my tests in `./testthat/testthat/` folder and a `./testthat/testthat.R` file as follows:

```
library(testthat)
library(rpostgisLT)
test_check("rpostgisLT")
```

All the tests require that the `testthat` package is attached (thus I didn't use the `testthat::function` referencing.

Just after restarting R (without `testthat` attached) I try to run `devtools::document()` but it breaks, because it doesn't find the `testthat` functions that I use in the tests. Of course, after attaching `testthat` `devtools::document()` runs through.

Why does `devtools::document()` look into the `/tests` folder? Shouldn't it only document functions in the `/R` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`devtools::document()` is a wrapper for `roxygen2::roxygenize`. If you read the documentation of the latter it says:

> Note that roxygen2 is a dynamic documentation system: it works using by inspecting loaded objects in the package. This means that you must be able to load the package in order to document it.

And also there is an argument `load_code` which says:

> A function used to load all the R code in the package directory. It is called with the path to the package, and it should return an environment containing all the sourced code.

Therefore, it looks like it is reading all `.R` files. However, I have a feeling that it skips all .R files that start with `test_` in the name (otherwise I would  have seen my packages break as well). I think the problem is your `helper_db.R` file where you use `testthat` functions in a file not starting with `test_`.

Comment: Hm, thanks that clears things up. So I was just not using `document/roxygenize` correctly. However, if it excludes the `test_` files, it would probably make sense to skip the whole directory.